# What's wrong with this PHP Password form? I can't find it

Tags: php, forms, if-statement

PHP Code:

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['pwsubmitted']))  {
        $pwsub=$_POST['pass'];
        if ($pwsub != "TEST"){
                $s=1;
                $msg = "Incorrect Password";
                $msg2 = "Try Again";
            }
        else if ($pwsub == "TEST"){
                $s=2;
                $msg = "Password Accepted";
                $msg2 = "Your Download Is Below";
                $msg3 = "";
            }
            // so I can see what's going on when form submit happens
            echo "s="; var_dump($s); echo "</br>";
            echo "msg="; var_dump($msg); echo "</br>";
            echo "msg2="; var_dump($msg2); echo "</br>";
            echo "msg3="; var_dump($msg3); echo "</br>";
    }

    ?>
```

Form, Placement Shown Below:

```
<div class="passform">
            <form id="pwform" method="post" action="">
            <input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="pwsubmitted" />
              <center>
                <span class="titleblue">Enter The Password</span>
              </center>

           <input name="pass" id="pass" type="password" class="password"  />

        <input name="submit" type="submit" class="submit" style="cursor: pointer;" value="" /></div>
        </form>

        </div>
```

Other Code:

```
<?php 
if (isset($_POST['pwsubmitted'])) {
if ($s == 1) { Do This };
if ($s == 2) { Do This };
}
<?php if(!isset($POST['pwsubmitted'])) {
?>
<HTML FORM FROM ABOVE HERE>
<?php } ?>
```

When I submit the form... nothing happens.  The original form stays up as if the pwsubmitted post variable isn't set.  There's two different things that happen, either a msg saying try again, or it shows the content.  Neither occur.

What did I do wrong??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your HTML you have this input field

```
<input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="pwsubmitted" />
```

In your PHP you're using

```
if (isset($_POST['pwsubmitted']))  {
```

But the name of that field is `submitted`.  Try

```
if (isset($_POST['submitted']))  {
```

Comment: DOH... I feel so stupid.  What an idiotic miss.  Works now.  Thank you Aaron!

Comment: Plus, this is a bad variable to test on. If they've submitted the form then the input that you need to make sure has been posted is the `pass` input. You don't need another field, you can just use `if(isset($_POST['pass']))` and you SHOULD use this variable because the next code relies on it.

Answer (score 1):

You should check for $_POST['submitted'] (name, not value of input).